# Java JPA - "Query argument id not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution"

Tags: java, jpa

I have an Entity class called `Pilot` with the following defined named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Pilot.findById", query="SELECT p FROM Pilot p where p.id = :id")
```

And another one called `Flight` with this named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Flight.findById", query="SELECT f FROM Flight f where f.id = :id")
```

Then i have a method that does the following:

```
TypedQuery<Flight> fQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Flight.findById", Flight.class);
fQuery.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(flightId));

Flight f = fQuery.getSingleResult(); 

TypedQuery<Pilot> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Pilot.findById", Pilot.class);
fQuery.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(pilotId));

Pilot p = pQuery.getSingleResult();
```

But for some reason when i call it i get the error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument id not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.
...
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a cut and paste error...

```
TypedQuery<Pilot> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Pilot.findById", Pilot.class);
fQuery.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(pilotId));
^^^^^^
```

You are setting the id on `fQuery` twice. Try changing the one for pilots to `pQuery`. Like this:

```
TypedQuery<Pilot> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Pilot.findById", Pilot.class);
pQuery.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(pilotId));
^^^^^^
```